# Get Firebase Cloud Messaging history using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to get Firebase cloud message history on my Nodejs project, but I do not find any API or Google Library to do so? Is it possible any way or I have missed some documentation to view. I have viewed this documentation earlier https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*firebaser here*

There is no public API for accessing the campaign data of the Messaging panel in the Firebase console. It's a valid request though, so I recommend [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report).